# Can't get value of Map<BigDecimal, String> by key

Tags: java, jsf, hashmap, bigdecimal

I have a map like

```
Map<BigDecimal, String> functions = new HashMap<BigDecimal, String>();
```

When I try to access the value of map from a JSF page, it displays nothing. I checked the size of map and it returns a number, it seems not empty. Here is the JSF page code

```html
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.permissions}" var="permission">  
    <p:column>
        #{bean.functions[permission.functionId]}   
    </p:column>                     
</p:dataTable>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Thanks Balusc and mendoza

Comment: The answer of Dima should not have been accepted. His answer is utterly wrong and misleading. In order to get the right answer, you should provide an SSCCE. Most likely cause is that you used a key of the wrong type.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

`BigDecimal` is a bad key for `HashMap`, it uses the BigDecimals memory address as the key, so even if you have 2 equal values, its a different key, try using the `toString()` of the BigDecimal as the key

Comment: I have changed Map to this and filled the map key part with 
**BigInteger.toString()** 
`Map<String, String> functionMap = new HashMap<String, String>();`

And try to acces the map from JSF page like this 
`#{mybean.functionMap[permission.functionId.toString()]}`

`permission` is an object iterated in a datatable.

Comment: This answer is utter nonsense. The `BigDecimal` has [a perfectly fine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) method. User2262540: In other words, you were actually using `BigInteger` and not `BigDecimal`? Thus, you were actually trying to use a `BigInteger` as key on a map where `BigDecimal` is used as key?

Comment: You know many objects has this problem, so its always better to do a toString

Comment: and you are so smart, please be my friend

Comment: @BalusC I genarated  my entities from an oracle database and the P.K fields are BigDecimal so that I should work with Bigdecimal.I checked the code but I couldn't detect a confussion like you said Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Two BigDecimals are not equal if their scales are not equal even if they represent the same numeric value. That is why they may not make good Map keys.

For two BigDecimals representing the same values with different scales compareTo() will return 0, but equals() will return false.